# Showing piece of code line by line

Tags: beamer

I want to show some program code line by line. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english]{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Slides with code}
\begin{itemize}
\item <1-> A piece of  code
\item[] <2-> \begin{lstlisting}[caption=,belowskip=-5pt]
int main(void)
\end{lstlisting}
\item[] <3-> \begin{lstlisting}[caption=,belowskip=-5pt]
{
\end{lstlisting}
\item[] <4-> \begin{lstlisting}[caption=,belowskip=-5pt]
   int i;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Now this is error-prone a painstaking. Is there another way to produce these slides?

Comment: You still have to `\pause` on each line, but it's better than having to restart the listing every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mathescape` to insert appropriate `\pause`s within the code, resulting in an easier way to negotiate the code reveal:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Slides with code}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=,mathescape]
int main(void)
$\pause${
$\pause$   int i;
$\pause$}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed the pause. Is this better that using `escapeinside=||` and then use `|\pause|`?

Comment: You could probably move `mathescape` up to the lstset.  Then it would be basically the same as `escapeinside=$$` (although `$$` may break things).  So my guess is "better" would boil down to: does your code otherwise use the character `|` or `$`?

Comment: That would be problematic if the code uses `$`, indeed. Better is to set the escape characters on a per listing basis, or use `mathescape` when is can be used.

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw: True. You'd have to use whatever suits your needs specifically. Not sure whether C uses `$`. Regardless, you can adjust this on a `lstlisting` basis, if needed.